# Add Genesis PHP line to post_info

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP statement

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'jetpack-post-views', true ); ?>
```

This i used by a wordpress plugin called "Jetpack post views"

It asked me to place the provided code anywhere on the page to see the post views.
I want it on "genesis_entry_header" with the other post_info

I don't know how to do that, and I look everywhere for a solution before I post this.

Thank you

Comment: `genesis_entry_header` is it a function in genesis theme?

Comment: @jogesh_pi I think it's a hook, and yes it's in Genesis theme. 
Look at this page, you may know how it's supposed to be done
[gregrickaby](http://gregrickaby.com/genesis-code-snippets/)

Sorry PHP is just not my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

```
function wp_87978_jpv(){
    global $post;

    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'jetpack-post-views', true );
}
add_action('genesis_entry_header', 'wp_87978_jpv');
```

Comment: Great man, that's how it's done, except of one thing. update your answer please. replace the "return" with a "echo" ... First I tried the return, it didn't show anything, when I changed, now I see the views number.

Comment: One more thing please. How can I add text next to the rendered result? I'd like it to show as Visits: XXX

Comment: @BilalKhoukhi I can't get what you are talking about, but as i guess you said _"add text next to the rendered result?"_ use `.` to append the result, ie - `echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'jetpack-post-views', true ) . "Add As HTML whatever you want.";`

Comment: What I want exactly is to show a text in the line, before the number of views.. your example rendered a text. but it was on the second line. I want to add the the HTML (<p>Visits:</p> 240 ) something like that

Comment: @BilalKhoukhi _it was on the second line_ to add in the same line you have to modify the it with some CSS, with `echo "<div class='visits_container'><p class='visits'>Visits: </p>" . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'jetpack-post-views', true ) . "</div>";`